# Subquery not grouping returned data correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck on this query, I have been trying all day to group data based on customer but no luck, can anyone help.

```
SELECT S.Name AS 'CstName', 

       S.MinPrice - SUM(coalesce(c.Balance,0))  AS 'Blc',

       S.NumberOfItems AS 'Sold'


FROM Cst c, (
SELECT c.Name, c.address, c.Balance, (Min(s.Price)*i.Qty) AS MinPrice, SUM(i.Qty) AS NumberOfItems
FROM             dbo.Cst AS c 
             INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Odr AS o ON c.Name = o.Cust 
             INNER JOIN
                         dbo.inc AS i ON i.Order_no = o.Order_No 
             INNER JOIN
                         dbo.spls AS s ON i.Item = s.Item
WHERE        i.Item = s.Item AND o.Cust =c.Name
group by i.Qty, c.Name, c.Balance, c.address) S


GROUP BY S.Name,S.MinPrice, S.Address, S.Balance, S.NumberOfItems
```

The results should only show Tom Mary once

```
CstName   Blc    Sold 
Tom      207.69   1.00 
Tom      210.00  12.00 
Tom      224.45  10.00
Mary     217.47  6.00 
Mary     237.54  12.00
```

Comment: Why don't you use only   `GROUP BY S.Name`  instead of `GROUP BY S.Name,S.MinPrice, S.Address, S.Balance, S.NumberOfItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to group by and just display one row per customer, you need to aggregate the columns you are not using in the `GROUP BY`

So in your `SELECT`, you should aggregate `S.MinPrice` and `S.NumberOfItems` and remove them from your `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT S.Name                   AS 'CstName', 

       SUM(S.MinPrice) - SUM(coalesce(c.Balance,0))  AS 'Blc', -- Based on your need you can use any of the aggregation functions

       MAX(S.NumberOfItems)              AS 'Sold' -- Based on your need you can use any of the aggregation functions

...

GROUP BY S.Name
```